# Remove non alphanumerical characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I tried using both lines below:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $string);
```

But, if `$string` has a single quote, it is replaced by `"039"` and I don't understand why:

> don't

becomes

> don039t

Comment: Provide string you working with please.

Comment: I know *why* it's being replaced with that *value,* it's because `'` is character code point number 39. What I don039t know is why it's being replaced at all :-) Make sure it's not being modified somewhere else such as a "real_escape_string" or whatever it's called.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I would guess the original string likely looks something like `don&#039;t`.  It only replaces (`&#;`) since they are not `a-zA-Z0-9\s`...

Comment: @JoLibertaire Please accept the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

In don't Instead of single quote you are using `&#039;`. In html view it display as single code. While replacing(preg_replace) spacial characters will remove and **039**(from `&#039;`) only remaining.

Comment: That's a viable answer, didn't think of that.

Comment: Not sure if i understand correctly. I just tried running html_entity_decode() before preg_replace, but still 039

Comment: html_entity_decode() will show the single quote instead of &#039;. But it will not replace.

Comment: It should work if using `$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Try Scopey Answer its working fine.    
echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES));

Comment: @Mani: Why wouldn't it work? ... `'` is not `a-zA-Z0-9\s`, so `preg_replace` should replace it...

Comment: @l'L'l : Hoo sorry its working fine. I did some mistakes...  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, your string is encoded with `htmlentities`.

Try:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES));
```

See [this example](https://3v4l.org/kKDt4)

Specify `ENT_QUOTES` to make it deal with quotes.

If you are still looking for a way to remove characters, without decoding your entities, you can try

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9& ]|&(#[0-9]{2,3})?/i", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$exampleString = "Hi! Jo libertaire. This is working fine \"Yes absolutely fine\".Don't say its not working. you can try this string. :)";
$result= preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $exampleString);   
print $result;
```

I don't have a server for php so I tried this in an online editor and it's working fine.